# Searches are missing posts when using favorites quick buttons and manual searches

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, search, bookmarks

Not sure where to ask this question, if it belongs some where else comment so and I'll move this. But why is this post:
[Python Pyglet Using External Fonts For Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476629/python-pyglet-using-external-fonts-for-labels/58500680#58500680) not showing up on this filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyglet

It was working this morning, and opening it in an incognito window works. But for whatever reason there seams to be an issue with the filters and searches on SO whenever I use my "favourite tags" on the right to jump to a quick search.

[image: screenshot]

Is this a known problem, and if so, how do I fix it? *(Without wiping my entire cache which contains stuff I really need)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top of the page says

> ## Questions tagged [pyglet]

That means answers, like yours, won't show up in the search results.

Further down it says

> #### 129 questions with no answers

Since the corresponding question *does* have an answer, it won't show up either.

To fix this, you need to adjust your filter:

[image]

or click one of the other tabs ('Newest' or 'Active'). Filters are personal, so the incognito window just shows the 'Newest' tab.

Comment: fml, you are correct. I had no idea that writing `[pyglet]` in the search box automatically applied my filters. That's pretty counter intuitive but I guess good for those who searches for things often. But I still think that searching manually in the search box shouldn't auto-apply things, that's adding black magic wizardry to something a user inputs. But yea, that's the reason.